# R loop through read.delim 404 file not found

Tags: r, loops

I have made a little loop to retrieve data in .txt form from a website.
The data that I like is spread over multiple days for example this month day 1-16.

The problem is that some data isn't uploaded on weekends due to the nature of the data (stock market details).

When I try the for loop it stops putting the data into a variable as soon as it doesn't find a date.

I've tried using next and Try catch method to skip the error and continue but nothing seems to be working so far.

```
my_data <- list()

for (i in 01:13){

my_data[[i]] <- read.delim(sprintf("http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvol202005%02d.txt", i), header=TRUE, sep="|")

if(GET(my_data)$status_code!=200) next

}
```

gives me the following error:

[image]

and

```
my_data <- list()

for (i in 01:13){


  my_data[[i]] <- read.delim(sprintf("http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvol202005%02d.txt", i), header=TRUE, sep="|")

 my_data <- tryCatch(stop("Error"), error = function(e))
class(x)

}
```

Gives me the same error:

[image]

Does anybody know a way around this?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tryCatch` has to be around the reading part because that is where the error is thrown.

```
tryCatch({
  my_data[[i]] <- read.delim(sprintf("http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvol202005%02d.txt", 
                             i), header=TRUE, sep="|")
  }, error = function(e) print(e)
 )
```

Comment: Very silly of me thank you again Jan much appreciated!